# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

So I have to prove 2 things:

1. That $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \mathbb R, x>0$.
2. That $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \mathbb R$.

For #1, I know that $\frac{x^n}{n!} >0$, which means that I can find an upper bound and use squeeze theorem. For #2, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: For (2), use the fact that $|a_{n}|\rightarrow 0$ implies $a_{n}\rightarrow 0.$

Comment: $c_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}$, $|c_{n+k}| \le |c_n| \, |x/n|^k$

Comment: Depending on what you have available for you to use, you can prove it via the convergence of the MacLaurin series for $e^x$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$ (where this convergence can be simply proven by the ratio test). See my answer on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129489/limit-nx-x-as-x-tends-to-infty/2129500#2129500

Answer (score 2):

I think I've answered this question before, but note that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, so for every fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the series converges, thus the sequence of the terms $\{\frac{x^n}{n!}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ must converge to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, otherwise, the sum would not converge.

Comment: It is the opposite : you prove $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges and  $f'(x) = f(x)$ so that $f$ is an exponential to obtain $e^x = f(x)$

Comment: @reuns, not really, I used the fact that $f(x)$ converges to prove that the sequence of terms cannot go to anything but zero. Suppose that the limit is not zero, then $f(x)$ cannot be convergent.

Comment: This logic is fine, but you may as well include a proof that the series converges, to show that this isn't a circular argument.

Comment: @Bungo, I think this is nice: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136683/convergence-of-the-ex-taylor-series

Comment: Well, you don't need the fact that the series equals $e^x$. It suffices to show that the series converges for all $x$. The ratio test makes this very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given $x$, take $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N>x$. Then, for $n >N$,
$$\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{x^N}{N!} \cdot \frac{x^{n-N}}{(n!/N!)} \le \frac{x^N}{N!} \cdot \left(\frac{x}{N+1}\right)^{n-N} .$$

Comment: I understand the inequality, I'm not too sure on how to prove the limit of that goes to 0.

Comment: @MarkDodds Observe that $x/(N+1) < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of support for Koto:

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the exponential series

$\star)$ $\exp(x): = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ converges absolutely.

Hence: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\dfrac{x^n}{n!}| = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Proof of $\star$):

Ratio test:

With $a_n: = \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ we get for

$x\ne 0$ and $n\ge 2|x|$:

$|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| =$

$ |\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\dfrac{n!}{x^n}|=$

$\dfrac{|x|}{n+1}\le 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

**First Answer**
The series 
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
converges then $$\frac{x^n}{n!}\to 0$$

OR
**Second Answer**
Use the following famous Stirling formula: Given $x>0$
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2n} }=\sqrt{\pi}. $$
and $$|x^n| =e^{n\ln |x|}$$

Comment: Stirling's Formula is a bit of overkill here.  Note that $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$, which can be shown using elementary analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.  Then, we have

$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|\le \frac{|x|^n}{\left(\sqrt{n/2}\right)^n}=\left(\frac{2|x|}{n}\right)^n$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: @markdodds Mark, is this useful?  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac {x^n}{n!} = \frac{\overbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdots\cdots x}^{\Large n \text{ factors}}}{\underbrace{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots\cdots n}_{\Large n \text{ factors}}}
$$
When $n$ gets to be more than twice as big as $x,$ then multiplying by $\dfrac x n$ reduces the thing to less than half what it was. Then $n$ keeps growing (while $x$ does not) and at some point $n$ is more than three times as big as $x$ and then you're multiplying by $\dfrac x n < \dfrac 1 3$ and making the thing at each step less than $1/3$ what it had been. And so on$\,\ldots$ So it approaches $0.$

(That assumes $x$ is positive. If $x$ is negative, then think about $\dfrac{|x|^n}{n!}.$ It that approaches $0,$ then without the absolute value that still approaches $0.$

Comment: Or just use $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.  ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola : Do you think that's simpler than what I did?

Comment: It is very much akin to your approach.  It does save a bit of verbal explanation.

Comment: @MarkViola : This seems like the kind of situation in which being more verbal is desirable.

Comment: Perhaps so.  But using the estimate $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$ leads immediately to $\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|\le \left(\frac{2|x|}{n}\right)^n$.